# android can't put linearlayout under listview

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to put a linearlayout under a listview, if i put it above the listview i got an exception and the activity stop working suddenly, and when i put it under the listview it doesn't appear, what am i doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvRestaurants"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bDone"
            android:layout_width="153dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Done" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: each listview item has a checkbox, so the linearlayout is just has to buttons to approve the selected checkbox

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `android:layout_weight=1` to your ListView.

The reason why the other layout doesn't appear is because your listview takes all the place in the parent layout (`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`)

Comment: so have it make the hieght as "wrap content" ?

Comment: use android:layout_height="0dp" and android:layout_weight=1 for ListView.

Comment: yes thank you, i will accept your answer after 7 mins, best regards

Comment: please what is android:layout_weight= 1 did to make it work ?

Comment: You'r welcome, in order to well understand the `layout_weight` usage, I suggest you to read the `LinearLayout` documentation : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Comment: "wrap content" will bring a performance warning from ADT,  who will tell you setting "layout_height=0dp" will improve the layout performance by reducing one layout measurement parse.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using **RelativeLayout** instead. Using **LinearLayout** and specially **android:layout_weight** is expensive performance wise. This layout accomplishes what you need. The key is **android:layout_alignParentBottom** and **andoid:layout_above** properties. Try it out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bDone"
            android:layout_width="153dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Done" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvRestaurants"
        android:layout_above="@id/llButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `weight` Concept.
I did some changes in your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvRestaurants"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/llButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bDone"
            android:layout_width="153dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Done" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bCancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Do changes according to your requirement**

Answer (score 0):

To save the overhead, provide listView with **layout_weight="1"**

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_weight="1"    // The MagicLine
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and you LinearLayout with gravity="bottom"

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

 // here will be views, you want to put with in your LinearLayout

    </LinearLayout>
```

Also you can put a LinearLayout beneath a list view,  would be the use of a Relativelayout.

**Here is a sampleStructure.**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="constantHeightofLinearLayout" /> // here the constant height of the linear Layout or buttons, should be inserted

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" //this is the line, that would put this linearLayout beneath your Listview
        android:layout_height="constantHeight" // this height should be the marginBottom of ListView
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

 // here will be views, you want to put with in your LinearLayout

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```